# Custom field not being freezed by South in Django

Tags: python, django, django-south

In my Django model I created a custom field called LocationField following this tutorial [Django admin Google Maps](http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/django-admin-google-maps-location-picker-with-jquery).

Now my problem is migration using south doesnt seem to be working. It gave me an error

```
! Cannot freeze field 'SilverInningsHelpline.classified.location'
! (this field has class SilverInningsHelpline.widgets.LocationField)

! South cannot introspect some fields; this is probably because they are custom
! fields. If they worked in 0.6 or below, this is because we have removed the
! models parser (it often broke things).
! To fix this, read http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork
```

To fix this, I added the inspection rules as defined by the documentation of South as follows:

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([
    (
        [Classified],
        [],
        {
            "location": ["LocationField", {"blank": "true"}]
        }
    )
], ["^southut\.fields\.Classified"])
```

where Classified model contains the LocationField. My classified model is as follows:

```
class Classified(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20, default=0)
    secondary_number = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20, default=0, blank=True)
    more_numbers = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', blank=True)
    image = S3DirectField(upload_to='s3direct', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    location = LocationField(blank=True, max_length=255)
```

Any suggestions to fix this would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't bother to read the doc.

1. You're passing your model class (`Classified`) where `add_instrospection_rules` expects your field class (`LocationField`).
2. The 'keyword arguments' dict is supposed to describe which keyword args your field expects, not a description of how your field is used in a given model class
3. The qualified field name pattern at the end should match your field's qualified name, not some random mumbo jumbo combination of what's in the tutorial and your model class name.

Comment: Thanks for the very rude explanation.Your solution is anyway not the one that works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Newtt: Thanks for your very rude comment. I took on my spare time to read your post, read the doc, and post an answer pointing at least three obvious errors in your code, which I think qualifies as "suggestions to fix this". If you tried to fix your code and had another error, please update your post. Oh and yes, there's nothing rude in stating the obvious - what `add_introspection_rules` expects IS documented, and I never had a problem adding instrospection rules to south just following the doc.